# GROUP BY in elasticsearch using "aggs", not working for me in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I want to use the GROUP BY equivalent in elasticsearch for the result I get from 'filter'.

I tried to use the 'aggs' to do it, but I am not sure how.

```
$params = [
'index' => $table_name,
'type' => '_doc',
'size' => 4894,
'body' => [
 'query' => [
  'aggs' => [
   'some_key_to_group_by' => [
    'bool' => [
     'filter' => [
      ['terms' => ['key1' => $array1]],
      ['terms' => ['key2' => $array2]],
      ['terms' => ['key3' => $array3]],
      ['terms' => ['key4' => $array4]]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
];
```

I had already got the result which was not grouped with respect to anything,
Now I expected a grouped response but the echoed result was like this...

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no  
[query] registered for [aggs]","line":1,"col":18}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you'r mixing queries and aggregations. The `aggs` section is a sibling of the `query` one, not a child one:

This should work:

```
$params = [
'index' => $table_name,
'type' => '_doc',
'size' => 0,
'body' => [
 'query' => [
  'bool' => [
   'filter' => [
    ['terms' => ['key1' => $array1]],
    ['terms' => ['key2' => $array2]],
    ['terms' => ['key3' => $array3]],
    ['terms' => ['key4' => $array4]]
   ]
  ]
 ],
 'aggs' => [
   'some_key_to_group_by' => [
      'terms' => ['field' => 'key1', 'size' => 100]
   ]
 ]
]
];
```

Comment: Thanks ! Some clarifications: The query part has to be blank ? what about filter ? I have only single key to group by

Comment: I want the aggregation to apply on the result of the query before it. If they are siblings, how can I do this ?

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I am getting the same output I got without aggregation, I might need further clarification. I figure 'some_key_to_group_by' can be replaced by any string, the 'field' has to be kept as it is, and the 'key1' has to be replaced the the key I want to perform GROUP BY with,  right ?              Let's say I have a key called 'state', if I GROUP BY 'state' and echo the output, each 'state' value has to be shown only once right ? It's not happening.

Comment: That's correct. You might want to set `size` to 0, since you're not interested in the query hits, just the aggregations. It's very probable that the results you expect are there but very far below in the response. Setting the size to 0 would only show you the aggregations.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it. Inside the buckets I got only 10 results like `{"key":12,"doc_count":80},{"key":48,"doc_count":56} ..... `  is that a limit because size is set to zero ?

Comment: See my updated answer, there's another size parameter that you can set to get more buckets, i.e. 100